# Hide product attributes from additional information tab in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

How to hide certain custom product attributes on single product pages additional informations tab?

Note: I don´t want to hide everything, just specific attributes.

For e.g i would like to hide `"pa_size"` to name one it it.

Only found this one, but its for a products weight.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' , '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 8):

For all custom product attributes you can hide them from additional information tab just deselecting the option **"Visible on the product page"** under product settings > Attributes tab:

[image]

1) **To remove the product dimensions**, you can disable that with the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_dimensions', '__return_false' );
```

2) **To remove everything from the tab** ( weight, dimensions and custom attributes) use this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 );
```

3) **To fine tune what you want to display**:

You can override `single-product/product-attributes.php` template via your active child theme *(or active theme)* that displays everything in this product tab.

So you can remove any html block, that displays those details, or customize it…

---

Official documentation:  [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. But here i have to hand pick products and deselect the attributes one by one? I have like 80.000+ products :) Would be great to filter them out in functions.php so new added products will get affected as well by default. Also i don´t want product attributes to be disabled at all, just hiding from the front-end table under additional informations tab.

Something like
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_"what_ever_attribute", '__return_false' );

Comment: Please see: https://s14.postimg.org/mnhg2xyc1/additional-informations-attributes.jpg

Product attributes here are not identifiable in html otherwise i could add some css to simply hide them here like .pa_size {display:none;}

Comment: @romu Why instead you don't remove this product tab? This is easy and will solve this problem

Comment: Because i want to show some of the information. Otherwise i would not ask or? :)

Comment: You mean overwrite the /product-attributes.php ? No, not tested yet. But sounds good. I will look at this today. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer for the same/similar issue, wanting to remove the additional information tab. I came across this post using the 
[woocommerce_product_tabs filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742813/2218436)

I added it to functions.php and the additional information tab is no longer added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `functions.php` can cause problems with shipping, see here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/5985#issuecomment-322541850

Simply copy the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php` to `wp-content/themes/YOUR_CHILD_THEME/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php` and add an `if` to check for the attribute. (As LoicTheAztec mentioned in #3)

This is from WooCommerce 4.4.1:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Product attributes
 *
 * Used by list_attributes() in the products class.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <?php // Hide weight attribute in frontend ?>
        <?php if ( esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ) !== 'weight' ): ?>
            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
                <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
                <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```